# Javascript delayed load of content within div element

Tags: javascript

I have some code which delays the general page load of my website, which is included at the very top of the page (adverts to be specific, with tracker scripts which sometimes are slow to fully load.)
These ads loading slowly delay other JS scripts/effects/functions from working until they finish.. e.g. scrollers/sliders etc etc

What i was wondering, is what is the code to load content into these specific div elements maybe after the page is loaded?? (EDIT: Changed to just ask when the rest of page is loaded, to ammend to comments below)

(Ive seen similar samples of code to this.. but never quite got it to function right)

this is the original code

```
<div id="ad-header"><script type='text/javascript' src='http://url.com'></script>
```

then tried changing to, and changes i keep making are unsuccessful at making it work. needs to load the ad into the ad-header id spot

```
var delay = 3000;
setTimeout(
    function()
    {
        var oScript;
        oScript = document.createElement("script");
        oScript.type = "text/javascript";
        oScript.src = "http://url.com";
        document.body.appendChild(oScript);
    },
    delay
);
```

Comment: You need a `load` event listener to be sure the document has been loaded before you modify it. There you can start your timeout, if still necessary.

Comment: @PointedEars brings up a good point. Do you really need to delay them 2 seconds or is delaying them until the page loads good enough?

Comment: delaying it until the rest of the page would work ok i would think. how could i go about doing that? is it similar or a complete change of JS?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.body.appendChild(oScript);` you should probably be doing `document.getElementById('ad-header').appendChild(oScript);`

The rest of your code looks correct as it is.

Comment: The approach is *not* correct. There is a race condition here, and actually your suggestion makes it worse.